# Default Hindi font is showing even after implementing any kind of Hindi font. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts, hindi

In my Android app, I am trying to implement outline based Hindi font but after implementing any such font the Hindi text is showing in default font only whereas the is working perfectly with English Text.

I am doing it programmatically (Java) and using XML both but getting same result.

Anyone can help please.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you - https://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-use-hindi-font-in-android-application

Download the .ttf file from any website. (Like Ananda-Lip-Bold as given in the website whose link I mentioned).

Create assets folder. Inside that create a fonts directory. Paste the .ttf file inside fonts directory

Now in the Activity Java Class, add :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anytextview);
    Typeface fontHindi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Ananda Lipi Bold Cn Bt.ttf"); //Any font which you pasted in the directory
    tv.setTypeface(fontHindi);
```

Please tell me whether it works or not in the comments.
If not update your code after implementing this code.

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for your try but as I mentioned I am able to change font and also Hindi text is displaying. But in the case of Hindi, font style is not changing after implementation of font whereas same font is working fine for English.

Comment: Sorry there is a mistake in my answer. Actually you have to create assets folder. Inside that create a fonts directory. Paste the .ttf file inside fonts directory.

Comment: I am making a Hindi Recipe App where I used a hindi font and its working fine. I did the same procedure in my app also. So it should work now

Comment: I was implementing the same code but issue was something different. It was not supporting most of the Hindi font downloading from outside. When tried from google font it is supporting. Anyway, thank you for your contribution as I realize that there is something wrong in font after seeing your answer.

Comment: Most Welcome . Can you tell your font name?

Comment: I used kruti dev font (you may know the name). Which font did you used?